# Interactive supervised classification tool greyed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification

I'm using ArcMap to perform a classification. The problem is in the classification wizard, all tools like maximum likelihood classification and other are still available except the interactive supervised classification tool, that greyed out.
Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Are the tools licensed? Have you enabled that license?

Comment: Select some training samples.  From the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/an-overview-of-the-image-classification-toolbar.htm) "*There must be at least two training samples present for this option to be available.*"